# microsoft visual studio 2012 pro setup failed

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installation

I had instal visual studio 2010 and 2008.Now am try to install visual studio pro 2012.But it throwing an error as shown. Visual studio installation error message is

```
Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 x64 Minimum Run time - 11.0.507.
Cannot find the requested object.
```

Am in confused state if any body have the same issue or any body know the solution  please let me know

Update:

My Windows 7 was not updated at that time.Once i `check updates` and install all recommended and optional updates.Then am able to install the Visual studio 2012 with web developer option.

`Finally my issue got resolved` thanks for your time.

My suggestion:

Please make sure that you `closed all application` and your `windows was updated` before installing Visual studio 2012 and My recommendation is use `*.iso` file instead of `*.exe`

Thanks.

Comment: Presumably you're installing on a 64-bit edition of Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I get this problem too, and my ISO file was corrupted..

I used md5summer to check the SHA1 key and after another download its worked

Check these steps:

1. Make sure your VS2012 installer is not corrupted, you can download one fresh one from the Microsoft official site here: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-premium-2012
2. The user account you are using to install VS2012 Premium should be one of the Administrators group.
3. The user account should have full access to the C:\ProgramData\Package Cache folder.